# active_admin jquery-gems are making mess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently installed active_admin gem.

Everything is working fine on Rails4, but jquery in my bootstrap page is not working anymore.

All animations are broken now, its like static page.
Any way of fixing it?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Did you add any other jquery in your assets javascript folder ?

Comment: @Bharatsoni nope, nothing is added. Fresh installed ActiveAdmin, started it, its working, but all animations are lost.

Comment: Please look into this https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/468

Comment: The key is to open `application.js` and `application.css` and remove the `require_tree` .. This is a bad default on Rails part because the user should specify load order anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

What i did was, moved file `active_admin.js.coffee` from `app/assets/javascript/` to `vendor/assets/javascript` . Also moved file `active_admin.css.scss` from `app/assets/stylesheet/` to `vendor/assets/stylesheet/` .

In `application.js` from  content nothing was added, and require_tree is needed for both of those 2 files (application.js. and application.css )(no need to delete `require_tree`).
Same goes for `active_admin.rb`, nothing was added there either.

Application is now working  correctly, loading css and jquery (my 1.7 version, not AA one).

-Michael

Answer (score 1):

The key is to open application.js and application.css and remove the require_tree .. This is a bad default on Rails part because the user should specify load order anyway

Also do not forget to ad these lines in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
  # == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
  #
  # We recommend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
  # up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
  # and feel.
  #
  # To load a stylesheet:
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'

  # You can provide an options hash for more control, which is passed along to            stylesheet_link_tag():
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_print_stylesheet.css', :media => :print
  #
  # To load a javascript file:

 config.clear_stylesheets!
 config.register_stylesheet "application.css"
 config.clear_javascripts!
 config.register_javascript "application.js"
```

Then in you application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap.switch
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require active_admin/base
```

....

Comment: clear_stylesheets and clear_javascript wont delete my previously installed JS and implemented CSS im using for my bootstrap?

Comment: this is the way to use Active admin if you not configure these it will not work

Comment: I just deleted `require_tree` in `application.css` and `.js` & added commands in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` but after that all my initial settings for page on localhost:3000 are gone. no css and nothing. just pure html. I just need to enable previously used jquery for bootstrap theme im using.

Comment: your css in which folder /app/assets

Comment: Oh sorry didnt see your edit. Ok this is the situation: 
After adding your code its still same, even tho its calling error on `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>` but after i remove that one i get the same, which is No Css on page and no JavaScript either.(pure html page on localhost:3000)
what do you mean by "my css in which folder/app/assets"

Comment: also i get this error : `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-switch'`

Comment: did you require this `//= require bootstrap.switch` in application

Comment: Yes i do. this is content of my `application.js` file : http://pastebin.com/DrKv4fsi
 and this is of `application.css` : http://pastebin.com/pyCQKQQT
Also this is my `active_admin.rb` : http://pastebin.com/bYefxNWp
Can you check and see is everything alright there?? Thanks

Comment: I prefer @import in css  secondly you do not have the library file bootstrap-switch.css in the folder that's why it is giving `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-switch'`

Comment: Solved it. Posted as result. Thanks anyway.